# Makefile - include library

Tags: c, module, makefile

I'm trying to write a module that uses the function nanosleep().

when my make file runs it changes the build libary by doing:
make  -C /lib/modules/2.6.18-128.4.1.el5/build M=/workspace/lcd-winstar-0.0.1 modules

nanosleep is declare in /usr/include so my makefile cant find it.
what lines should I add to my makefile to include this location as well?????

thanks

Comment: `nanosleep` is part of the standard library on POSIX systems. If it's not being found, something is very wrong with your build environment.

Comment: For future reference, it's worth seeing if you can execute the desired command by hand before complaining that make isn't doing it right because that tells you if the problem is in your understanding of the build steps or is something to do with make.

Comment: I can't excute the function from the shell for testing. Let me explain again.. with gcc the compiler id familiar with the function usleep and nanosleep. but because I need to make file with " make -C /src/kerneles/$(uname -r)/include " it doesn't recognizes the other liabries that the functions declared in...
for example there is two time.h file but woth diffrent code:
1. /usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-128.4.1.el5-i686/include/linux/time.h
2. /usr/include/time.h 
the wanted functions are declared only in the second one..

Answer (score 3):

> -I dir 
>       Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for
>   header files. Directories named by -I
>   are searched before the standard
>   system include directories. If the
>   directory dir is a standard system
>   include directory, the option is
>   ignored to ensure that the default
>   search order for system directories
>   and the special treatment of system
>   headers are not defeated .

&&

> -Ldir
>       Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l

Comment: thank you for your answer.. I already tried to do so.. and still it didn't work. my Makefile is in the follwing comment..:
I wonder why there is soo many "time.h" in the file system.. cause how the compiler choose between two files if both libaries are included??

Comment: make  -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules -I/usr/include

Comment: thank you for you answer.. Though I'm still struglling with that..
my code dont recognize other liabries it first need the kenel liabries to compile the module.. soo I have to do -C and change the compile libary..  but then it still don't recognize other liabries by -I.